# Amazon Athena Cross Account Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Can I create a database and table in Athena service within my account to access S3 data in another account?

I went over the below link and I assume as per this documentation both Amazon Athena and S3 bucket have to be in the same account and access is provided to the user in another account.

`https://console.aws.amazon.com/athena/home?force&region=us-east-1#query`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Access Control Policies - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/access.html):

> To run queries in Athena, you must have the appropriate permissions for:
>
> - The Athena actions.
> - The Amazon S3 locations where the underlying data is stored that you are going to query in Athena.
> - ...

So, it seems that the **IAM User** who is executing the Athena query requires access to the Amazon S3 location.

This could be done by adding a Bucket Policy to the S3 bucket in the other account that permits the IAM User access to the bucket.

To explain better:

- `Account-A` with `IAM-User-A` and AWS Athena
- `Account-B` with `Bucket-B` that has a Bucket Policy granting access to `IAM-User-A`

Comment: In this scenario , can IAM-User-A be replaced by IAM-Role-A. I would be able to use a role but not a user.

Comment: Yes, you can use a Role to call Athena (once you assume the role), and the Bucket Policy can grant permission to a Role instead of a User.

Comment: Thanks , one last question , instead of bucket policy , can I add IAM policy to role in Account B to allow access to bucket b ?

Comment: If you want to run Athena (and create tables) in `Account-A`, then you will need to use `Role-A` in `Account-A`. Therefore, you would need a Bucket Policy on `Bucket-B` to grant access to `Role-A`. If the role instead exists in `Account-B`, then using that role will not provide access to Athena in `Account-A`. When using an AWS services you are either acting as a User or as an assume Role, both of which belong to a specific account. Only the account that defines the User/Role can assign permissions, _OR_ a Bucket Policy can grant permissions cross-account.

Answer (score 2):

This answer deals with the additional information that:

- A Lambda function in `Account-A` must be able to create a table in Amazon Athena in `Account-B`

I haven't tested it, but I think you will require:

- `Role-A` in `Account-A` for the Lambda function that:

  - Permits `AssumeRole` on `Role-B`
- `Role-B` in `Account-B` that:

  - Permits access to Amazon Athena and the source bucket in Amazon S3
  - Trusts `Role-A`

The Lambda function will run with `Role-A`. It will then use credentials from `Role-A` to call `AssumeRole` on `Role-B`. This will return a new set of credentials that can be used to call Amazon Athena in `Account-B`.

Comment: Thank you! One change here though , in my scenario : A lambda function in account A must be able to create a table in Amazon Athena in Account A which points the source S3 bucket in account B.

Comment: That will not work unless you can add a Bucket Policy to `Bucket-B`. It is not possible for `Account-A` to grant permissions on resources in `Account-B`. You could (maybe) grant `Role-B` permission to use Athena in `Account-A`, which would mean that `Role-B` can use Athena in `Account-A` and S3 in `Account-B`.

Comment: Yes , I was trying to see if I could add Athena (account a) and s3 ( account a) for storing results to role B. I believe this would mean that I have to create the database and table in Athena after assuming account b’s role in my lambda.

Comment: Is S3 in Account A or Account B?

Comment: S3 is in account B . When I query data using Athena , it stores the results in another bucket. So I want to use Athena to query data in S3 bucket in account B and store the results of that data in S3 in account A.

Comment: You'll need a bucket policy on either the source bucket or the destination bucket, since they are in different accounts.

Comment: I’ll be able to add bucket policy (destination bucket) in account A as it’s in my account. I believe I should add a bucket policy to all role B to write to the bucket if I’m not wrong.